# Calling cmd and passing arguments with Python subprocess

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I am trying to get a command to run within python that otherwise works fine as a bat file or in the `cmd` command prompt.

Python version 2.7.9.

The following works fine in the command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Aquatic Informatics\AQUARIUS\runreport.exe" -Report="NHC_chart_1Week_1Series" -TimeSeries="Precip Total.24hr@FK Intake Forecast" -Server="aqserver-van" -username="admin" -password="admin" -label="Battery Voltage Data" -OutputFile="C:\Aquarius\Reports\Altagas\Summary\24hr_Precip_Forecast.pdf"
```

This basically calls a program (`runreport.exe`) and passes a bunch of arguments to it.  If things go well a file is created.

It seems I should be able to do the same in python with `subprocess.call`
I have tried many different versions of the code but none of them run the program correctly.  Below is my current code:

```py
import subprocess

run_report_program_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Aquatic Informatics\AQUARIUS\runreport.exe'
reportname="-Report=NHC_chart_1Week_1Series"
timeseries="-TimeSeries=Precip Total.24hr@FK Intake Forecast"
server="-Server=aqserver-van"
user="-username=admin"
passwrd="-password=admin"
output="-OutputFile=C:\Aquarius\Reports\Altagas\Summary\24hr_Precip_Forecast.pdf"
result=subprocess.check_output([run_report_program_path, reportname, timeseries, server, user, passwrd, output], shell= True)
```

The program runreport's does 'pop up' but runs to quick and doesn't output the desired result, instead I get the error below. Does anyone see the issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\aquarius\scripts\API_import_and_trigger_reports_py\python_scripts\call_run_reports\test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    result=subprocess.check_output([run_report_program_path, reportname, timeseries, server, user, passwrd, output], shell= True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Aquatic Informatics\\AQUARIUS\\runreport.exe', '-Report=NHC_chart_1Week_1Series', '-TimeSeries=Precip Total.24hr@FK Intake Forecast', '-Server=aqserver-van', '-username=admin', '-password=admin', '-OutputFile=C:\\Aquarius\\Reports\\Altagas\\Summary\x14hr_Precip_Forecast.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Also, in the command prompt it usually returns a nice set of errors (like time series not found, or report created successfully), I also don't get these. Is it possible to get these returned within the python session?

Comment: One way to debug the issue would be to copy the command line in a variable and split the args using shlex.split(command_line) and then pass the args to subprocess.

Comment: Nothing in your command line requires using `shell=True`. This job will be simpler and more secure without involving cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_output` raises an exception if your program does not return zero. Try insert an *r* before the *output* string, that maybe is why your program fails.

Also it passes the output as a return value, so you would not see any output even if your program passed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the output to

```
output=r'-OutputFile=C:\Aquarius\Reports\Altagas\Summary\24hr_Precip_Forecast.pdf'
```

Fixed the issue.  Thanks you